# Universal App with localized app name crashes

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

After a small update to my app, it crashes quite often with the following stack trace:

```
Frame    Image                                 Function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Offset        
0        KERNELBASE.dll                        RaiseException                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0x00000036    
1        mrmcorer.dll                          Microsoft::Resources::ReportFatalException                                                                                                                                                                                              0x00000052    
2        mrmcorer.dll                          Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::Core::CResourceManagerFactory::get_Current                                                                                                                                                        0x0002b1b0    
3        mrmcorer.dll                          Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::Core::CResourceManagerFactory::GetCurrentResourceManagerInternal                                                                                                                                  0x0000004a    
4        mrmcorer.dll                          _GetResourceManagerForCurrentApplicationInternal                                                                                                                                                                                        0x00000026    
5        mrmcorer.dll                          GetStringValueForManifestField                                                                                                                                                                                                          0x00000140    
6        twinapi.appcore.dll                   Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::SetAppDisplayName                                                                                                                                                                     0x00000048    
7        twinapi.appcore.dll                   Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::InitializeApplicationServer                                                                                                                                                           0x0000012a    
8        twinapi.appcore.dll                   Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::RunInternal                                                                                                                                                                    0x00000192    
9        twinapi.appcore.dll                   Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::Run                                                                                                                                                                            0x00000012    
10       backgroundTaskHost.exe                main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0x0000006c    
11       backgroundTaskHost.exe                __mainCRTStartup                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0x000000ec    
12       backgroundTaskHost.exe                mainCRTStartup                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0x0000000e    
13       ntdll.dll                             RtlUserThreadStart                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0x00000016
```

The app name is localized in several languages, default language is "en".

Localized the "Display name" and "Package display name" in the Appxmanifest like this: "ms-resource:AppName".

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the crash yet.